# PyQt custom widget in c++

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, python-sip

Can I write custom Qt widget in pure C++, compile it and use in PyQt?

I'm trying to use the ctypes-opencv with qt and I have performance problems with python's code for displaying opencv's image in Qt form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to write a Python wrapper for the widget, using the `sip` library (which is used by PyQt). There is a [simple example](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/using.html#a-more-complex-c-example) for a Qt/C++ widget in the documentation.